# On the intuition of "at what speed does a ladder leaning on a wall falls to the ground?"

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, intuition

**Problem**.  A ladder of $6$ meters is inclined against a wall, making up an angle $t$ with the wall.  As the ladder slides down, the distance between the wall and the ladder's base increases up to its length.  At what speed does the ladder slide when the angle is $t = \pi/6$?  What about $t = \pi/3$?

**Edit**.  The problem (as written by me) has an ambiguity which explains why my intuition failed in the first place.  The ambiguity is that I don't specify which point of the ladder is of concern here.  Different points of the ladder move in different speeds.  See the accepted answer.  Thanks to @DavidQuinn for first spotting the ambiguity.

**A solution**.  The sine of $t$ equals the distance of interest, $x$, over the length of the ladder.  In symbols, $\sin(t) = x(t)/6 \implies x(t) = 6 \sin(t)$.  So we're interested in

$$x'\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = 6 \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = 6 \times \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = 3 \sqrt{3},$$

meaning $3 \sqrt{3}$ meters per radian.

We're also interested in
$$x'\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) = 6 \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) = 6 \times \frac{1}{2} = 3,$$

meaning $3$ meters per radian.  We're done.

**Intuition and question**.  I've seen a ladder fall like that and it seems to me that it hits the ground with greatest speed possible.  But, in this problem, the ladder seems to be losing speed as the angle opens up from $\pi/6$ to $\pi/3$.  The cosine function is greater at angles near zero than at angles near $\pi/2$, which is consistent with the results.  So I'm puzzled.  Is the model wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by “speed of the ladder”? Every point on the ladder is moving with a different speed since it is rotating and translating.

Comment: if you want to know the speed, meters per second, why are you calculating the rate of change of $x$ with respect to an angle?  I don't think "t" was a good choice of variable name.

Comment: @DavidQuinn, good question.  I meant the speed of the base of the ladder that slides on the floor.  I'm going to edit the question.

Comment: You are using the derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$, the angle, as the “speed”, which is patently false.

Comment: @MatthewTowers, I think I used $t$ as an easy-to-write Theta.  So we're interested in meters per radian, not per second.  (But, yes, I agree that $t$ is often taken as time.)

Comment: You really need to treat this as a mechanics problem, for which you will need to make modelling assumptions such as the ladder being a uniform rod, and no friction at contact with the wall and the ground.

Comment: @DavidQuinn, would you add that as an answer?  I'm afraid you're seeing a lot more than I do.  Right now I'm perfectly happy with TonyK's answer.  I would appreciate if you turn it into an idealized mechanics problem (using only basic calculus, which is what I have) explaining what are the difficulties with the reality of the problem as I wrote it.  If you have the time.  Thank you.

Comment: There are numerous treatments of this problem to be found, for example, this https://advlabs.aapt.org/document/servefile.cfm?ID=14039&DocID=4399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the $y$-coordinate of the point of contact with the wall that speeds up over time. The $x$-coordinate of the point of contact with the ground speeds up at first, but the slows down to $0$. You can see this if you imagine that the ladder somehow falls through the ground while still attached at its endpoints (you could implement this with rails and sliders) $-$ this $x$-coordinate will start to *decrease*.

Comment: Wow.  I see.  Indeed, my vision is in one perspective and the calculations in another.  Thank you so much.  Order is back in the house.